# How to create a Color Picker in android to apply color to a view

Tags: android

Is there any way to create color picker in android like in photoshop

Comment: Hi please  check the Android color picker `https://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/`

Answer (score 0):

check out this github project.
This is a beautiful project.

https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker

How to add dependency?

This library is not released in Maven Central, but instead you can use JitPack

add remote maven url in allprojects.repositories

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

then add a library dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13'
}
```

or, you can manually download aar and put into your project's libs directory.

and add dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'[arrFileName]', ext:'aar')
}
```

check out latest version at releases
Usage

As a dialog

```
ColorPickerDialogBuilder
.with(context)
.setTitle("Choose color")
.initialColor(currentBackgroundColor)
.wheelType(ColorPickerView.WHEEL_TYPE.FLOWER)
.density(12)
.setOnColorSelectedListener(new OnColorSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onColorSelected(int selectedColor) {
        toast("onColorSelected: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(selectedColor));
    }
})
.setPositiveButton("ok", new ColorPickerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedColor, Integer[] allColors) {
        changeBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    }
})
.build()
.show();
```

As a widget

```
<com.flask.colorpicker.ColorPickerView
    android:id="@+id/color_picker_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:alphaSlider="true"
    app:density="12"
    app:lightnessSlider="true"
    app:wheelType="FLOWER"
    app:lightnessSliderView="@+id/v_lightness_slider"
    app:alphaSliderView="@+id/v_alpha_slider"
    />

<com.flask.colorpicker.slider.LightnessSlider
    android:id="@+id/v_lightness_slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    />

<com.flask.colorpicker.slider.AlphaSlider
    android:id="@+id/v_alpha_slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    />
```

Comment: Hello, the color picker looks great, but I'm having some trouble initiating and using it. I'd like to use it as a dialog and assigning a selected hex color to a view. For instance, `.wheelType(ColorPickerView.WHEEL_TYPE.FLOWER)`, what is the ColorPickerView? Is it the view that I want to change the color of? Also, can it only change the background color value?